# Domain services seem to require only a fraction of the total queries defined in repositories -- how to address that?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I'm currently facing some doubts about layering and repositories.

I was thinking of creating my repositories in a persistence module. Those repositories would inherit (or implement/extend) from repositories created in the domain layer module, being kept "persistence agnostic".

The issue is that from all I can see, the necessities of the domain layer regarding its repositories are quite humble. In general, they tend to be rather CRUDish.

It's in general at the application layer level, when solving particular business use-cases that the queries tend to be more complex and contrived (and thus, the number of repository's methods to explode).

So this raises the question of how to deal with this:

1) Should I just leave the domain repository interfaces simple and then just add the extra methods in the repository implementations (such that the application layer, that does know about the repository implementations, can use them)?
2) Should I just add those methods at the domain level repository implementations? I think not.
3) Should I create another set of repositories to be used just at the application layer level? This would probably mean moving to a more CQRSesque application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should react to the realities of your business / requirements.

That is, if your use-cases are clearly not "persistence agnostic" then don't hold on to that particular restriction. Not everything can be reduced to CRUD. In fact I think most things worth implementing can't be reduced to CRUD persistence. Most database systems relational or otherwise have a lot of features nowadays, and it seems quaint to just ignore those. Use them.

If you don't want to mix SQL with other code, there are still a lot of other "patterns" that let you do that without requiring you to abstract access to something you actually don't need abstraction to.

On the flipside, you build a dependency to a particular persistence system. Is that a problem? Most of the time it actually isn't, but you have to decide for yourself.

All in all I would choose option 4: Model the problem. If I need a complicated SQL to build a use-case, and I don't need database independence (I rarely if ever do), then just write it where it is used, end of story.

You can use other tools like refactoring later to correct design issues.

Answer (score 0):

The Application layer doesn't have to know about the Infrastructure.

Normally it should be fine working with just what Repository interfaces declared in the Domain provide. The concrete implementations are injected at runtime.

Declaring repository interfaces in the Domain layer is not only about using them in domain services but also elsewhere.

> Should I create another set of repositories to be used just at the
>   application layer level? This would probably mean moving to a more
>   CQRSesque application.

You could do that, but you would lose some reusability.

It is also not related to CQRS - CQRS is a vertical division of the whole application between queries and commands, not giving horizontal layers different ways of fetching data.

Comment: I think you (as the other poster) didn't get the gist of the OP. "You could do that, but you would lose some reusability." The matter is not gaining or losing reusibility. The matter is that the application layer will most of the times contain entities, value objects and tables that do not exist at the domain level and that a domain level repository could not even represent.

Comment: The connection between what I'm referring to and CQRS is that the Application Layer repositories will tend to be all query-side, with big queries and no inserts / updates (those have already been covered in the domain-level repositories).

Comment: @devouredelysium Sorry but I really don't follow you. Your title talks about *domain services* and further down you mention *necessities of the domain layer regarding its repositories*. It's clear that you are talking about the **Domain** layer as a consumer of repositories and contrast it to the Application layer as a consumer of repositories, right?

Comment: What does it have to do with CQRS? Why would the Domain be all about commands, and more importantly, why would the Application be all about queries?

Comment: the domain layer will contain in its defined interfaces for the repositories the methods it needs to get its stuff done. that will include (for sure) any write methods like insert/update(entity). but the domain model generally speaking only cares about forcing domain ARs/entities invariants, and as such all kinds of workflows / sagas, etc are left to the upper layer, the application layer. now, it is generally at that level that you will have to take care of all the rest of the coordination logic, workflows and long-running processes, as well as possible UI concerns coming from

Comment: the presentation layer. Those will be (read) queries and not writes.

Comment: "Why would the Domain be all about commands" <- because the domain is about enforcing (domain) invariants (hence, about writing). there's no point in having that much querying logic at that level.

Comment: I disagree. You will very often call `repository.add()` or `remove()` from the Application layer. If your Domain uses any repo (which I don't recommend), it will likely be from a domain Service so you have to call something like `repository.get()` to get the aggregates.

Comment: @guillame:  "You will very often call repository.add() or remove() from the Application layer." If you call a repository.add() from the application layer then you can't protect the possible domain model invariants.. at the domain layer, where they should be enforced. Regarding your next point, as stated in the OP, the repositories at the domain layer tend to be CRUDish, so yes, they will have a getById() method.

Comment: @devouredelysium I also disagree with *"the application layer will [...] contain entities, value objects and tables that do not exist at the domain level"* by the way. Entities and value objects belong in the Domain layer. The amount of application-specific data to store is usually dwarfed by that of domain data.

Comment: "Entities and value objects belong in the Domain layer." let's go by parts: where are you going to put permission related objects (such as User, UserGroup, UserRole, etc)? in the domain layer? where are you going to store workflow related data (such as classes representing DB processes, etc?) Where are you going to be storing entities from subdomains that are only tangentially related to the application, but needed nonetheless (such related to other systems that you need to integrate with)?

Comment: *"where are you going to put permission related objects?"* => ACL is a subdomain of its own, so yes, you can put them in a Domain layer. Again, the concepts of Entity and Value Object only make sense inside a domain layer.

Comment: *"If you call a repository.add() from the application layer then you can't protect the possible domain model invariants.. at the domain layer, where they should be enforced. "* => Sorry, but this is a big misunderstanding of how layering works in DDD right there.

Comment: @devouredelysium I suggest you have a look at sample DDD implementations  out there ([Vaughn Vernon's](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/tree/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration) just to name one) and reconsider some of the assumptions behind your Q.

Answer (score 0):

Given that a repository is not about querying but about working with full aggregates most of the time perhaps you could elaborate on why you may need to create a separate set of repositories that are used only in your application/integration layer?

Perhaps you need to have a read-specific implementation that is optimised for data retrieval:

> This would probably mean moving to a more CQRSesque application

Well, you'd probably want to implement read-specific bits that make sense.  I usually have my data access separated either by namespace and, at times, even in a separate assembly.  I then use `I{Aggregate}Query` implementations that return the relevant bits of data in as simple a type as possible.  However, it is quite possible to even map to a more complex read model that even has relations but it is still *only* a read model and is not concerned with any command processing.  To this end the domain is never even aware of these classes.

I would not go with extending the repositories.